# Weird relationship in cvQueryFrame( ) instruction

Tags: macos, opencv, computer-vision

I noticed that there is a weird behaviour with `cvQueryFrame` isntruction.

I usually work with `IplImage* frame;` as the variable to contain the actual frame.

```
frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
```

With this instructions, all goes fine but if you want to save for example next frame with another `IplImage*` variable because you want to do any other thing. I obtain a compilation error throwing a message about size and other things.

It's looks like there is an invisible relationship between the variable you first use with `cvQueryFrame()` and you cannot break this relation until you release the capture var.

I think the unique relationship is with the capture variable.

Any option to save different frames with differents `IplImage*` variables? 
Any other ideas ???

I use OpenCV under OS X and installed using MacPorts.